# Using Union tool in QGIS creates gaps and overlaps

Tags: qgis, union

After using the Union tool on QGIS I get hundreds of gaps and overlaps between polygons on the resulting shapefile.
If I zoom to the fullest on those gaps and overlaps they are always lines, they never show any area.
Sometimes the error disappears after I move the vertices associated with the gaps, but it doesn't always happen and there being hundreds of errors it would take a lot of time.
Is there any solution for not getting this kind of error, or any way I can fix my shapefile?
.[image: The images shows part of the shapefile where you can see the erros, wich are just lines between polygons]

Comment: You could try a small buffer before unioning

Comment: Maybe a valid answer?

Comment: You can also try [snap to grid](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgissnappointstogrid) before and/or after the union

Comment: Just tried snap to grid and got more errors than before. I left the 1 meter grid spacing that comes default, are there better values? Thank you

Comment: What type of layers are you using, shapefiles, file geodatabases. geopackages, etc.?  If a file geodatabase does an input have true curves and what is its validated tolerance?  I would check my inputs geometry and run a v.clean with a suitable tolerance followed by remove duplicates on each layer, then try the union.

Comment: This is a common issue because most GIS formats are not aware of topology. There are many old questions and answers about the topic. Some examples: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71809/is-there-a-dissolve-st-union-function-that-will-close-gaps-between-features
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247205/solve-wrong-topological-error-after-union
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277334/shapely-polygon-union-results-in-strange-artifacts-of-tiny-non-overlapping-area.